# Using Mocha --fgrep with subdirectories runs all tests

Tags: grep, mocha.js

I'm using Mocha to run a number of tests and I wanted to tag some as smoke tests, e.g. `("[smoke] Test Foo")` then run `mocha -f [smoke]`. `fgrep` isn't working and *all* tests are triggered.

I have multiple services within my test framework:

```
service1
- lib
- resources
- test
-- foo
-- bar
service2
- lib
- resources
- test
-- foo
service3
- lib
- resources
- test
-- bar
....
```

I have defined the Mocha test path as `"**/test/**/*.test.@(js|ts)"`, and tried to use this path to narrow down the grep, as well as trying `--recursion`:

```
mocha -f [smoke] --recursion
mocha "**/test/**/*.test.@(js|ts)" --fgrep [smoke]
```

Each time all tests are being triggered instead of just the ones I've added the `[smoke]` keyword to. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure `[smoke]` is actually making it to `mocha`? You might need quoting in your shell.

Comment: Ahhhh, you're right.... I was passing it in via a shell command and it was stripping the quotes. switching to `"--fgrep \"[smoke]\""` has solved it.... so frustrating. Thanks @jonrsharpe. If you add that as an answer I can accept it